# Why does $ x\mathcal{R}y \iff |x| >|y| \text{ or } (|x|=|y| \text{ and } x>y) $ not allow a utility function representation?

Tags: relations, economics

Suppose we have the preference relation $\mathcal{R}$ defined on the interval $[-1,1]$ by

$$ x\mathcal{R}y \iff |x| >|y| \text{ or } (|x|=|y| \text{ and } x>y) $$

How do you show that this relation does not allow a utility function representation?

Where a utility function representation should satisfy

$$x\mathcal{R}y \iff u(x)\geq u(y). $$

Answer (score 2):

A preference relation that allows a utility function has to be reflexive as $u(x) \ge u(x)$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$. However $1 \mathcal R 1$ doesn't hold.

Comment: I know there is a proposition which states that if the relation $\mathcal{R}$ is reflexive, complete, transitive and continious then there exists a utility function corresponding to the relation, but this propisition can't be used the other way around, i.e. showing that one of these statements is violated does not imply that relation does not allow a utility function.

Comment: Then your definition of a utility function using $\iff$ is wrong. Because clearly $u(x) \le u(x)$ implies that $\mathcal R$ is reflexive.